# Laravel Eloquent query for filtering Items by average reviews rating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have `Items` table, and every item has many reviews (`Reviews` table), and `Reviews` table has `rating` column (1, 2, 3, 4, 5; Star Rating System). And it's a polymorphic relationship:

[image]

I have rating filter that needs to do a query: find `Items` where the average rating from `Reviews` table is >= `rating` from the user input:

[image]

I did manage to write SQL query in two ways, but **I just cannot convert it to Eloqent, so it can be applied as a filter**. Here are my two SQL queries:

[image]

Here are some Eloquent tries (that don't work):

[image]

[image]

[image]

This kinda query works, but again, I can't seem to apply it on the `Builder`:

[image]

Can someone write me a proper Eloquent query for this filter? Thanks.

Comment: It'd be better if you pasted the code instead of a bunch of screenshots. That will ease copy/paste/modifying from people trying to help you

Answer (score 0):

About the 2 SQL queries you can't convert to Query Builder.

```php
# Query 1:
$results = DB::table('items')
    ->select('items.id')
    ->join('reviews', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('reviews.reviewable_id', 'items.id')
                    ->on('reviewable_type', 'App\\Models\\Item');
    })
    ->groupBy('items.id')
    ->havingRaw('round(avg(reviews.rating)) >= ?', [4])
    ->get(); // you can check with toSql()
```

```php
# Query 2:
$results = DB::table('items')
    ->select('items.id')
    ->where(function ($sub) {
        return $sub->selectRaw('round(avg(reviews.rating))')
                   ->from('reviews')
                   ->whereColumn('items.id', 'reviews.reviewable_id')
                   ->where('reviews.reviewable_type', 'App\\Models\\Item');
    }, '>=', 4)
    ->get(); // you can check with toSql()
```

Query 2 looks like the last filter you tried. I think the problem is you're not using `whereColumn` to compare the `items.id` and the `reviews.reviewable_id` columns.

- `where('items.id', 'reviews.reviewable_id')` will take 'reviews.reviewable_id' as a string literal (`WHERE items.id = "reviews.reviewable_id"`)
- `whereColumn('items.id', 'reviews.reviewable_id')` will take 'reviews.reviewable_id' as a table column (`WHERE items.id = reviews.reviewable_id`)